# When doing a Smart Site Publish, the PublishContext.PublishOptions.Mode is "Full" instead of "Smart"

Tags: publishing, publishing-service

When I perform a `Site Publish`, there are 3 options - `Incremental publish`, `Smart publish` & `Republish`.

I'm capturing the `PublishMode` in a custom Handler and the results are:

For Incremental publish - Incremental
For Smart publish - Full
For Republish - Full

I'm expecting that the `PublishMode` would be `Smart` for the `Smart publish` instead of `Full`. Is that correct?

Using v10.3

**patch.config:**

```
<pipelines>
  <publish>
    <processor type="MyCode.Handlers.AuditPublish, MyCode"/>
  </publish>
</pipelines>
```

**AuditPublish.cs**

```
public class AuditPublish:PublishProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(PublishContext context)
        {
            var mode = context.PublishOptions.Mode.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be careful with making too many assumptions around the PublishingAPI, it has undergone a lot of changes in recent months and years.

Anyway, that said. "Full" and "Smart" are both "Full Publishes", but the "compareRevisions" flag will be `false` for a "Full" publish, and `true` for a "Smart" publish.

Answer (score 3):

If you decompile the `Sitecore.Kernel` dll there are 5 enums of **PublishMode** in the code `Sitecore.Publishing.PublishMode`.

1. **Unknown** - Unknown mode.
2. **Full** - Re-publishes everything.
3. **Incremental** - Every item change generates a record in list (f.e. PublishingQueue table).
4. **SingleItem** - Publishes single item.
5. **Smart** -  Publishes items that have different revisions in source and target.

Now if you check `PublishOptions` class it has several costructor and one of them is setting the mode like.

```
public PublishOptions(Database sourceDatabase, Database targetDatabase, PublishMode mode, Language language, DateTime publishDate, string userName, Replacer replacer)
{
   if (this.mode == PublishMode.Smart)
   {
       this.mode = PublishMode.Full;
       compareRevisions = true;
   }
}
```

That's the only reason you see this behavior and it is expected as per code.

Hope it helps!